# R: Summarize rows per month

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have made a dataframe which has a column with dates and columns with numeric values. I want this dataframe to group itself by month and summerize all the numeric values from the other columns per corresponding month.

Here is my dataframe example:

```
capture.date  Test1  Test2  Test3
2016-03-18      0      1      1
2016-03-18      1      1      1
2016-03-20      2      1      1
2016-04-12      1      0      1
```

I already tried some code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(capture.date) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

and:

```
aggregate(df[2:4], by=df["capture.date"], sum)
```

but both of these options return dataframes which summarize by daily date instead of month. How can I make it summarize by month instead of by day?

desired output:

```
capture.date  Test1  Test2  Test3
2016-03         3      3      3     
2016-04         1      0      1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract dates into the `%Y-%m` format in `group_by()` and use `summarise_if()` or `summarise_at()` to select which variables get be summed.

(Confirm that `capture.date` is `Date` class)

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date = strftime(capture.date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Date    Test1 Test2 Test3
#   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
# 1 2016-03     3     3     3
# 2 2016-04     1     0     1
```

---

#### Update!

Scoped verbs (`⁠_if`⁠, `⁠_at`⁠, `⁠_all`⁠) have been superseded by the use of `pick()` or `across()` in an existing verb.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Date = strftime(capture.date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should work

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

txt <- "capture.date  Test1  Test2  Test3
2016-03-18      0      1      1
2016-03-18      1      1      1
2016-03-20      2      1      1
2016-04-12      1      0      1"

data <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

data %>% 
  mutate(month = month(capture.date), 
         year = year(capture.date)) %>% 
  group_by(month, year) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.integer, sum) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate("capture.date" = paste(year, str_pad(month, 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), sep = "-")) %>%
  select(capture.date, Test1, Test2, Test3)
```

This will produce

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  capture.date Test1 Test2 Test3
  <chr>        <int> <int> <int>
1 2016-03          3     3     3
2 2016-04          1     0     1
```

You may need to change the function in `summarise_if` to something else than `is.integer` for your real data.

Comment: My bad, I updated my desired output. Can the date output look like 2016-03, 2016-04, etc instead of a new month and year column?

Comment: See updated text, though Darren Tsai's solution is more concise.

Answer (score 3):

**1) dplyr/zoo** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert each date to yearmon class which represents dates having no day and then summrize the numeric columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(yearmon = as.yearmon(capture.date)) %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, sum) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving this tibble:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  yearmon   Test1 Test2 Test3
  <yearmon> <int> <int> <int>
1 Mar 2016      3     3     3
2 Apr 2016      1     0     1
```

**2) zoo** This could alternately be done in a singhle `read.zoo` command. `fortify.zoo` could be used on the result if you want a data.frame as the result:

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum)
```

giving this zoo series:

```
         Test1 Test2 Test3
Mar 2016     3     3     3
Apr 2016     1     0     1
```

**2a) zoo with magrittr pipeline** This could alternately be written as this pipeline with magrittr (or dplyr) pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

df %>% read.zoo(FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum)
```

or to convert to data.frame

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

df %>% read.zoo(FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum) %>% fortify.zoo
```

**3) Base R** Using only Base R extract the first 7 characters of each date and then aggregate on that:

```
df2 <- transform(df, year.month = substr(capture.date, 1, 7), capture.date = NULL)
aggregate(. ~ year.month, df2, sum)
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  year.month Test1 Test2 Test3
1    2016-03     3     3     3
2    2016-04     1     0     1
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
capture.date  Test1  Test2  Test3
2016-03-18      0      1      1
2016-03-18      1      1      1
2016-03-20      2      1      1
2016-04-12      1      0      1"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```