# Summarizing daily data to monthy with year associated with each month

Tags: r, date

My data looks like this:

```
  edate          ids 
2018-07-28          2
2018-07-24          3
2018-07-24          4
2018-08-03          5
2018-07-22          6
```

So this is a day wise entry of ids.One day can have multiple entries of ids.This is the head of the dataframe.Actual data consists of more than 16k records and this is increasing everyday.

So i want my output to be like this:

```
Year     Month       Total_Entries
2017      Jan            2
2017      Feb            4
.
.
.
2018      Jan             3
2018      Feb             5
```

Also is it possible to get the data quarter wise?

```
Year     Quater      Entries
2017       Q1           25
2017       Q2           20
.
.
2018        Q1           15
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680287/r-summarize-rows-per-month/58680653#58680653

Answer (score 0):

We can get month and year from each date and use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(ids~month_year, transform(df, 
             month_year = format(as.Date(edate), "%b-%Y")), length)

#  month_year ids
#1   Aug-2018   1
#2   Jul-2018   4
```

Another way using `lubridate` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(edate = as.Date(edate), 
         year = year(edate), 
         quarter = quarter(edate)) %>%
         #Use month to get monthly data
         #month = month(edate)) %>%
   count(year, quarter)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(edate = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L), 
.Label = c("2018-07-22", "2018-07-24", "2018-07-28", "2018-08-03"), 
class = "factor"), ids = 2:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
mthly_summary <- aggregate(list(mthly_tot = df$ids),

                           by = list(mon_year = as.Date(df$edate, "%m-%Y")),

                           sum)


qtrly_summary <- aggregate(list(qtrly_tot = df$ids),

                          by = list(qtr_year = paste(gsub("[-].*", "", df$edate), quarters(df$edate), sep = " ")),

                          sum)
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
df %>%

  mutate(qtr = quarters(edate),

         mon_year = as.Date(edate, "%m-%Y")) %>% 

  group_by(qtr) %>%

  mutate(qtrly_to = sum(ids)) %>% 

  ungroup() %>% 

  group_by(mon_year) %>% 

  mutate(mthly_summary = sum(ids)) %>% 

  ungroup() %>%

  select(-c(ids, edate)) %>%

  distinct()
```

Data (thank you @Ronak Shah):

```
df <- data.frame(edate = as.Date(c("2018-07-22", "2018-07-24", "2018-07-28", "2018-08-03"), "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                 ids = 2:5)
```

Comment: Base R Solution runs but does not show any result whereas Tidyverse solution throws an error.Please help me out.

Comment: @Rahul use the data i have provided and then try again. Does this run?

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply.edate is a column with more than 16k rows.That can be same or not.And ids are all distict which is increasing everyday....